# Postgresql keeps throwing syntax error on FILTER

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have made this query that compares 2 result

```
SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*)::decimal/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05')*100),2)
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05'
AND planned = 'PLANNED'
GROUP BY planned'
```

The query above outputs `47.30` for the `PLANNED` Column while the next query outputs `52.70`:

```
SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*)::decimal/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05')*100),2)
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05'
AND planned = 'UNPLANNED'
GROUP BY planned
```

And this is the query I have made to compare the result of these 2 and make the column `PLANNED` and `UNPLANNED` become row:

```
SELECT
   unnest(array['colPlanned', 'colUnplanned']) AS months,
   unnest(array[col_planned, col_unplanned]) AS values
FROM(
    SELECT
        ROUND((
            COUNT(*)::decimal / (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05') * 100)
              FILTER (WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05' AND planned = 'PLANNED'),2) AS col_planned,
        ROUND((
            COUNT(*)::decimal / (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05') * 100)
              FILTER (WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05' AND planned = 'UNPLANNED'),2) AS col_unplanned
    FROM dashboard.event
    )t
```

Postgresql keeps throwing me a syntax error but upon checking all of my opening and closing () is okay.
Is there something I'm missing?

The error shown:

[image]

UPDATE:

Seems it's hard to ask this kind of question without giving a data, so I have made these query to show what i'm computing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05'), ROUND((COUNT(*)::decimal/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05')*100),2)
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05'
AND planned = 'PLANNED'
```

The above query outputs these:
[image]

The formula is basically getting the percentage of planned/unplanned that have occured on that day.

```
'((planned count or unplanned count) / overall_planned_count) * 100)'
```

is the formula i've created.

Now I can just run these query:

```
SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*)::decimal/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dashboard.event WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05')*100),2)
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05'
AND planned = 'UNPLANNED'
GROUP BY planned
```

To get the result for the `UNPLANNED` but the problem is that i also need to get the result for the `PLANNED`. I can also run them both but the problem will be  they will be columned like this:

```
col_planned         col_unplanned
____________       _______________
47.30                52.70
```

But i needed the it to become a row not column and look like these:

```
col_this              result
____________       _______________
 unplanned           52.70
planned              47.30
```

That's why the query i've created is creating a dummy row but the problem is the syntax error that it's throwing.

Comment: there is a 't' in the end of your query you saw it ? remove it

Comment: Always include the exact error message

Comment: It's need to work since if i removed it the error `subquery must have an alias` will show up.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen error is now included.

Comment: I think the `FILTER` should be right after the aggregate function `COUNT` since it affects it, not after the division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can simplify your query to this:

```
SELECT count(*) filter (where planned = 'PLANNED') / count(*)::decimal    as planned,
       count(*) filter (where planned = 'UNPLANNED') / count(*)::decimal  as unplanned
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE cast(event_start_adj AS DATE) = '2020-04-05'
```

I left out the `round()` part to focus on the actual query, but you can easily add that in

If you have an index on `event_start_adj` the above condition will not be able to use it. You will need to rewrite it to:

```
WHERE event_start_adj >= DATE '2020-04-05'
  AND event_start_adj < DATE '2020-04-06'
```

Comment: This worked. Tweaked it a little but still works :) Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would be more simply written using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT avg( (planned = 'PLANNED')::int ) as planned,
       avg( (planned = 'UNPLANNED')::int ) as unplanned
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE event_start_adj >= '2020-04-05'::date AND
      event_start_adj < '2020-04-05'::date + interval '1 day' ;
```

Note I changed the date comparisons to be more index compatible.

EDIT:

If you want the values in rows, it is just as simple:

```
SELECT planned, COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE event_start_adj >= '2020-04-05'::date AND
      event_start_adj < '2020-04-05'::date + interval '1 day'
GROUP BY planned;
```

Comment: made an edit on my question kindly see. BTW i've tried to run this query but it gives me a wrong computation and the planned/unplanned is a column.

Comment: @ElijahLeis . . . This should be doing the same calculation as your first two queries.  Can you set up a db<>fiddle to show what you are seeing?

Comment: The result of your query throws a  percentage that is already rounded off. My result was 47.30 your query threw a 47 but the 52.80 result your query threw 53.

Comment: Also it threw a result of planned/unplanned being a column not a row. Please see the screenshot on the edited question.

Comment: @ElijahLeis . . . `avg()` -- even of integer values -- returns a value with decimal places.  You can format it however you like.  Postgres would not be rounding the value to an integer.  You can easily see this here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=14ccd782f5a5e23e71ed8837480a9e56.